# Firebase EmailPasswordAuthProvider Does Not Exist on Type Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

In an Angular2 / TypeScript environment, the following code from Firebase documentation errors with "EmailPasswordAuthProvider Does Not Exist on Type Auth".

```
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth
Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account

Have installed the latest Firebase typings version: firebase@3.0.5

Note that other Firebase methods are working okay and that the auth object requires the open/close brackets e.g.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Comment: It's `EmailAuthProvider`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthProvider

Comment: I get the same error when using method: EmailAuthProvider
Note that I'm following the web implementation documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a bug in the typescript definitions. The Firebase team has been notified and is working on a fix. In the meantime use the following workaround:

```
(<any> firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider).credential
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't been able to resolve this yet. This code produces the same typescript error. The following line of code (have tried all sorts of variations too) fails with error: "undefined: Cannot read property credential of undefined". let credential = (firebase.auth() as any).EmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest firebase version 3.2.1. Older versions did not have a typescript definition file.

Comment: Upgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.2.1. Still seeing the exact same behavior and errors.

Comment: I cannot find EmailAuthProvider anywhere on the Firebase-admin SDK for node.

Comment: `EmailAuthProvider` is only available in the Firebase client SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is my temporary solution:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const credential = firebase.default.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, pass);
```